# Reload page without refreshing- postdata issue

Tags: php, csv

i need to stop data duplicate due to page reload..every time i reload the page without inserting CSV..i find duplicate

- what could be the issue?..the codes works fine

  ```
      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {

      $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
      $handle = fopen($file,"r");
      if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {

      while ($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"))
      {
      $a = $fileop[0];
      $b = $fileop[1];
      $c = $fileop[2];
      $d = $fileop[3];
      $e = $fileop[4];
      $f = $fileop[5];

      $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO hzy3o_zhgooglemaps_markers (title,  addresstext, published, baloon, icontype, mapid)

     values('$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$e', '$f')");

      }
      }
      }
     if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0) {echo $form} else {header("Location:      http://www.shambani.org /index.php?option=com_zhgooglemap&view=zhgooglemap&id=1&mapzoom=13&placemarklistid=&explacemarklistid=&grouplistid=&categorylistid=¢erplacemarkid=¢erplacemarkaction=&externalmarkerlink=0&mapwidth=&mapheight=&Itemid=177"); /* Redirect browser */
   exit();}

   ?>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="" >
    CSV<input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
    </form>
  ```

Comment: Duplicate "files" or duplicate "entries in DB"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this line:

```
if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0) {
      header("Location:      http://www.shambani.org /index.php?option=com_zhgooglemap&view=zhgooglemap&id=1&mapzoom=13&placemarklistid=&explacemarklistid=&grouplistid=&categorylistid=¢erplacemarkid=¢erplacemarkaction=&externalmarkerlink=0&mapwidth=&mapheight=&Itemid=177"); /* Redirect browser */
      exit();
} else {
      echo $form
}
```

Comment: @Fred -ii- dublicate csv records in the table

Comment: You'll need to do a sub-routine/function to see if data already exists in DB because doing the INSERT. @user3189234

Comment: the problem is that i am not that good in in scripting..what do you mean sub-routine/function

Comment: You need to do something like this `if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)` using the [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows) function. @user3189234 - That's the "basic" method to check if a record exists.

Comment: @Mary: I think you can because I don't see any use of it, it is uninitialized

Comment: one last Question..what does $handle,1000,",","'" mean..asume i have more than 10, thousand records will i need to replace 1000  to 10000?

Comment: @Syed Qarib:i have just deleted  and now its functioning perfect...many many many thanks to you..this i have done it for 4months  imagine

Comment: You are welcome .. btw you can find information on that @handle parameter from here : http://pk1.php.net/fgetcsv, '1000' in your case is not the number of results, its max characters in an item